# Rails 3.0.0.beta and Facebooker: anyone else seeing the following?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, facebooker, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails server seems to break after installing the facebooker plugin. Any suggestions on fixing this would be great.

I'm using rails 3.0.0.beta and facebooker.

Here are the steps and the error that I'm seeing:

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.0.beta
$ rails break; cd break
$ ./script/rails plugin install git://github.com/mmangino/facebooker.git
$ vim Rakefile #and add "require 'tasks/facebooker'"

$ ./script/rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.0.0.beta application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:91:in `const_missing'
    from /path/break/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker/adapters/adapter_base.rb:6
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:537:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /path/break/vendor/plugins/facebooker/lib/facebooker.rb:252
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:537:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /path/break/vendor/plugins/facebooker/rails/../init.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:537:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /path/break/vendor/plugins/facebooker/rails/init.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/plugin.rb:49
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/application.rb:71:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/application.rb:41:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0.beta/lib/rails/application.rb:41:in `method_missing'
    from /path/break/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:537:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:167:in `require'
    from config.ru:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Facebooker is known not to work with Rails 3](http://railsplugins.org/plugins/215-facebooker), which is not backwards-compatible.

See http://railsplugins.org for any future such inquiries until Rails 3 is mainstream.

Sounds like, sadly, Facebook apps will have to use Rails 2 until Facebooker becomes compatible.

Comment: Thanks; so the solution is to revert back to rails2 for the moment. Great!

Comment: Or contribute to Facebooker and help them fix it. Rails 2 sounds like the more viable option for those on a time constraint xP Though a site I recently saw comes to mind - http://nextsprocket.com/ - you can *pay* someone to make Facebooker Rails-3-compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of rails3 forked branches out there:
e.g. http://github.com/joren/facebooker/commits/rails3

they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This one works with Rails3 and the new facebook api:
http://github.com/funkensturm/facebooker-rails3

but it is very experimental and doesn't include the test etc.