# Are there any stable solutions for using Rails 3.0 and Facebook together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker

I've seen reports that Facebooker doesn't work with Rails 3.  I've noticed that there's a Facebooker2 project, but it doesn't seem to have any documentation and there's no information I can find about its Rails 3 compatibility.  Are there any good choices for getting Facebook Connect working with a website built on Rails 3.0.0 (beta4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see there are some fork about rails 3 in Facebooker. But nothing official.

[Rails 3.0.0.beta and Facebooker: anyone else seeing the following?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368389/rails-3-0-0-beta-and-facebooker-anyone-else-seeing-the-following)